# Making a Title scroll in a UIScrollView with the text below

Tags: iphone

I have a storyboard with a UIScrollView taking up the entire iPhone screen. I have a label at the top for the title, and then a textview below that which has text loaded into it from a .txt file. However when I scroll, it scrolls through the large body of text with the title staying put at the top of the view, even though the label is based in the scrollview rather than outside of it. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textView` has its own scrolling method built in, so your `textView` will scroll independently of your `scrollView`.  Create the title within the `textView` or set `text view` not to scroll in Interface builder and use your `scrollView`

Comment: excellently quick and most helpful! I did wonder why when I got to the bottom of the bulk of text the title finally disappeared! There must've been two scrolls going on! Answer Accepted and Appreciated!

Comment: Yes that was what was happening.  Glad it helped